# How can i edit my mask animation in VSE more precisely?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking, graph-editor, dopesheet

I created and animated a mask. I used it for a VSE strip. Since I retimed my VSE strip the mask no longer at the right time range. I realized I can edit the keys in the DopeSheet:

[image]

It is fine to offset the animation. However I'm interested in whether there is a way to edit the mask more precisely like editing in Graph Editor or editing specific control points of the mask?

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on a point of the mask and press <kbd>V</kbd> to set handle type - in  the menu of the *Image Editor/Movie Clip Editor*, in *Mask Mode* go to *Mask->Set Handle Type*.

There should be 5 choices: *Auto, Vector, Aligned Single, Aligned, Free*.

Once you pick one, they should show the handles - but be careful of distortions, the Free one tends to be not so destructive.